# Dataframe index (only) to CSV python

Tags: python, csv, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to convert some data to pandas dataframe. Somehow, the dataframe turned out to be empty. The print statement shows the following (part of it)

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: [count  "a" "33" "37" "asd7"]
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: [data  "2434" "33" "37" "name@email.com"]
```

I'd like to write the dataframe to a csv file. Since the dataframe is empty, can I write the indexes into a csv file like

```
count,data
a,2434
33,33
37,37
asd7,name@email.com
```

I know I can write a dataframe to csv using data.to_csv, but how do I achieve the above stated?

Answer (score 2):

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(index=["a", "33", "37", "asd7"], )
df2 = pd.DataFrame(index=["2434", "33", "37", "name@email.com"])
df1.index.name = 'count'
df2.index.name = 'data'
```

You already have objects similar to `df1` and `df2`.
Just do:

```
df1.reset_index(inplace=True)
df2.reset_index(inplace=True)

df3 = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
```

gives

```
   count data
0   a    2434
1   33   33
2   37   37
3   asd7 name@email.com
```

finally:

```
df3.to_csv("file_name.csv")
```

Comment: Not related to the question, but thanks for the `df1.index.name = 'count'`. Did not know you could name the index.

Answer (score 1):

Probably not the best approach but this normal `for/loop` with `zip` can write the csv as you asked:

```
df
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: [count, a, 33, 37, asd7]

df1
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: [data, 2434, 33, 37, name@email.com]

with open('combined_pd.csv', 'w') as f:
    for x,y in zip(df.index, df1.index):
        f.write(x + ',' + y +'\n')

>>>cat combined_pd.csv
count,data
a,2434
33,33
37,37
asd7,name@email.com
```

Comment: Looping with dataframes will likely be very slow and is more difficult to read.

Comment: @cd98, looping with dataframes of course will be slow. However, looping their indexes which are basically lists and write to file, will be much more efficient and quicker than `reset_index` and `concat` in OP use case. That said, I do like your approach to do things in `pandas` way :0